# The term 'Win32_computerSystem' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-3.0

I'm fairly new to Powershell scripting and have been playing around with a script I found online which queries all the systems in my domain and outputs bits of hardware information in a CSV. The script:

```
$testcomputers = Get-Content -Path 'C:\scripts\computers.txt'
$exportLocation = 'C:\scripts\pcInventory.csv'

foreach ($computer in $testcomputers) {
  if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Quiet -count 2){
    Add-Content -value $computer -path c:\scripts\livePCs.txt
  }else{
    Add-Content -value $computer -path c:\scripts\deadPCs.txt
  }
}

$computers = Get-Content -Path 'C:\scripts\livePCs.txt'

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    $Bios =  Win32_computerSystem -Computername $Computer
    $Sysbuild = Get-WmiObGet-WmiObject win32_bios -Computername $Computer
    $Hardware = Get-WmiObjectject Win32_WmiSetting -Computername $Computer
    $OS = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -Computername $Computer
    $Networks = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $Computer | Where-Object {$_.IPEnabled}
    $driveSpace = Get-WmiObject win32_volume -computername $Computer -Filter 'drivetype = 3' | 
    Select-Object PScomputerName, driveletter, label, @{LABEL='GBfreespace';EXPRESSION={'{0:N2}' -f($_.freespace/1GB)} } |
    Where-Object { $_.driveletter -match 'C:' }
    $cpu = Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor  -computername $computer
    $username = Get-ChildItem "\\$computer\c$\Users" | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object Name, LastWriteTime -first 1
    $totalMemory = [math]::round($Hardware.TotalPhysicalMemory/1024/1024/1024, 2)
    $lastBoot = $OS.ConvertToDateTime($OS.LastBootUpTime) 

    $IPAddress  = $Networks.IpAddress[0]
    $MACAddress  = $Networks.MACAddress
    $systemBios = $Bios.serialnumber

    $OutputObj  = New-Object -Type PSObject
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ComputerName -Value $Computer.ToUpper()
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Manufacturer -Value $Hardware.Manufacturer
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Model -Value $Hardware.Model
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Processor_Type -Value $cpu.Name
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name System_Type -Value $Hardware.SystemType
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Operating_System -Value $OS.Caption
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Operating_System_Version -Value $OS.version
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Operating_System_BuildVersion -Value $SysBuild.BuildVersion
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Serial_Number -Value $systemBios
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IP_Address -Value $IPAddress
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MAC_Address -Value $MACAddress
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Last_User -Value $username.Name
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name User_Last_Login -Value $username.LastWriteTime
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name C:_FreeSpace_GB -Value $driveSpace.GBfreespace
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Total_Memory_GB -Value $totalMemory
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Last_ReBoot -Value $lastboot
    $OutputObj | Export-Csv $exportLocation -Append -NoTypeInformation
  }
```

When I run the script, I get the errors below and not quite sure how to address them. I've also noticed that the line supposed to output the system's RAM always outputs 0. Any guidance would be much appreciated. I'm running Powershell 3 on Windows 7 if that makes any difference.

```
Win32_computerSystem : The term 'Win32_computerSystem' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path 
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.



Get-WmiObGet-WmiObject : The term 'Get-WmiObGet-WmiObject' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a 
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.



Get-WmiObjectject : The term 'Get-WmiObjectject' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Comment: in addition to the many code errors [*grin*], the  _structure_ means it will run relatively slowly. if you are running this against a large-ish number of systems, then using `Invoke-Command` with a list of systems will be faster - it will run the scriptblock on **_each system, in parallel_**. plus, the deprecated WMI calls are slower than the newer CIM calls. here's a simple demo of the idea ... >>> [PowerShell] basic remote parallel SystemInfo demo script - Pastebin.com — https://pastebin.com/cGL5biWH <<<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Syntax errors

Line 15:

```
$Bios =  Win32_computerSystem -Computername $Computer
```

You forgot to prefix `Win32_ComputerSystem` with `Get-WmiObject`. It's attempting to run `Win32_ComputerSystem` as a command, not evaluate a WMI class. To fix it, change the line to look like this:

```
$Bios = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $Computer
```

Line 16:

```
$Sysbuild = Get-WmiObGet-WmiObject win32_bios -Computername $Computer
```

There is no cmdlet called `Get-WmiObGet-WmiObject`. Change it to `Get-WmiObject`:

```
$Sysbuild = Get-WmiObject Win32_Bios -ComputerName $Computer
```

Line 17:

```
$Hardware = Get-WmiObjectject Win32_WmiSetting -Computername $Computer
```

This is another typo when trying to call `Get-WmiObject`. Correct the mispelling and it should work:

```
$Hardware = Get-WmiObject Win32_WmiSetting -ComputerName $Computer
```

## Why your RAM is always zero

Simply put, you're using the wrong WMI class when you set `$Hardware`. You can get the physical memory information from the `Win32_PhysicalMemory` class. Replace line 17 with:

```
$Hardware = Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory -ComputerName $Computer
```

and when you get the $totalRam, you can use the following calculation:

```
$totalRamBytes = 0
$Hardware.Capacity | Foreach-Object { $totalRamBytes += $_ }
$totalRamGb = $totalRamBytes / 1GB
```

Comment: And there's also `Get-WmiObGet-WmiObject` and `Get-WmiObjectject` in the two lines following that too... looks like something got pasted in the wrong place.

Comment: I would also suggest [math]::round($Hardware.TotalPhysicalMemory/1024/1024/1024, 0) might be more useful?

Comment: I've updated the answer for how to fix the "ram is always zero" problem

Comment: Might even use /1GB instead of /1024/1024/1024.

Comment: Thank you all so much! I clearly have a lot to learn but this has been very helpful! Just ran a test with the changes and I'm getting no errors.

Comment: No problem! As a newbie, one thing I'd recommend is reading your errors a bit more closely. Most of the time the message will (at least partially) reveal why your code is failing to run. In this case, when you see `The term "BLAHBLAHBLAH" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program`, you know that you have a command incorrect somewhere, a program isn't available on the `$PATH`, or you may not have a module loaded with the cmdlet you want. In any of those cases, you know it's trying to run a command that it can't find.

Comment: Understood. I did read them and was apparently misunderstanding them but makes crystal clear sense now. Thanks again.